# Git error : Couldn't set refs/heads/master

Tags: git

I'm having this problem regardless of a new clone , reinstalling git extension or even deleting the local repository . Any helps ? The full error log is this

```
git push --recurse-submodules=check --progress "origin" refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
Counting objects: 133, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Total 94 (delta 77), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: Couldn't set refs/heads/master
To M:/Madsanda Dev
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (failed to write)
error: failed to push some refs to 'M:/remote folder'
Done
```

The only thing I noticed here is

```
git push --recurse-submodules=check --progress "origin" refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
```

, is usually

```
git push --recurse-submodules=check --progress "origin" master:master
```

Please advice , thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a file `HEAD` inside `.git` folder and write in that file `ref: refs/heads/master`

Example:

```
echo ref: refs/heads/master >.git/HEAD
```

Comment: Hmm , this does allow me to push , but other people are not pulling my updated files and neither do I'm able to pull others update .

Answer (score 3):

I've had this error when my files were on a network drive folder.. Copying my project into local folder with full permissions resolved it.

Answer (score 3):

For me, closing my IDE (VS) fixed the issue.

Comment: Insane, but this worked for me too. VS code must be locking the repo with its git integration

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Source Tree. Running in Administrator mode worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Enough hints here to fix my problem with a repo on UNC share. NTFS permissions for non-admins were set to Write/Change. Elevating to Full control on the folder eliminated the error.